# SQlite permissions not enough for execution

Tags: python, sqlite, raspberry-pi

I'm developing a small project on raspberry pi based on sqlite3 and python. One of the scripts reads data from sensor and writes them to database (sensor_update.py), the other (cgi script, hello.py) reads last entry in database and prints it on the website. 
The problem is that the scripts can't write and read from database properly. I set ownership of both database and scripts to www-data and yet when I try to execute database-writing script I get following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sensor_update.py", line 35, in <module>
    log_temperature(temp)
  File "sensor_update.py", line 15, in log_temperature
    curs.execute("INSERT INTO temps values(datetime('now'), (?))", (temp,))
sqlite3.OperationalError: attempt to write a readonly database
```

I know already that it most probably means that permissions are not right. However ls -l gives output that should indicate that I did everything right:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/usr/lib/cgi-bin $ ls -l
total 20
-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data 744 Jan 16 20:54 hello.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data 475 Jan 16 20:40 hello.py.backup
-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data 163 Jan  3 22:40 hello.py.save
-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data 197 Jan  3 22:40 hello.py.save.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data 698 Jan 16 21:11 sensor_update.py

pi@raspberrypi:/var/www $ ls -l
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 root     root     4096 Jan 11 08:31 html
-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data 8192 Jan 16 21:11 log.db
```

Also the cron job doesn't seems to work on the sensor_update.py script. Both programs produce expected output when command is preceded with sudo.
Sensor_update.py code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import Adafruit_BMP.BMP085 as BMP085
import os
import datetime
import sqlite3

dbname = '/var/www/log.db'
# store the temperature in the database
def log_temperature(temp):

    conn=sqlite3.connect(dbname)
    curs=conn.cursor()
    temp = str(temp)
    curs.execute("INSERT INTO temps values(datetime('now'), (?))", (temp,))

    # commit the changes
    conn.commit()

    conn.close()

def display_data():

    conn=sqlite3.connect(dbname)
    curs=conn.cursor()

    for row in curs.execute("SELECT * FROM temps"):
        print str(row[0])+"     "+str(row[1])

    conn.close()


sensor = BMP085.BMP085()
temp=sensor.read_temperature()
log_temperature(temp)
display_data()
```

hello.py code (cgi script):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import Adafruit_BMP.BMP085 as BMP085
import cgi
import cgitb
import sqlite3

cgitb.enable()
dbname = '/var/www/log.db'

def get_data():
        conn=sqlite3.connect(dbname)
        curs=conn.cursor()
        curs.execute("SELECT * FROM temps ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1")
        result = curs.fetchone()
        return result

if __name__ == "__main__":

        result=get_data()
        print result
```

Piece of apache2 logs:

```
[Tue Jan 16 21:55:10.812282 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 964] [client ---:52835] Premature end of script headers: hello.py
```

Comment: Please post the code or minimal example as well.. otherwise it cannot be verified. Help will be more difficult without it.

Comment: @ZF007 Done, although they execute fine with sudo.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite needs to create a "journal" file in the same directory as the database to support ACID transactions, and so it needs write access to the directory the database is in as well as the database itself.

`/var/www` is probably owned by `root` and not `www-data` (you didn't use `ls -al`, but seeing as the `html` directory is owned by `www-data`, I'm assuming `/var/www` is as well). SQLite can't create the journal, so it opens in read-only mode to prevent possible corruption.

Either change the permissions of `/var/www` or put the database in a folder that the process opening the database has write access to.