# Sqlite connection working in one python file but not in another

Tags: python, database, sqlite, ubuntu, flask

I have recently brought my database files to my Linux server from Windows. The sqlite python code returns this error when attempting to connect to a database file. It has worked in the past and has only stopped working recently. I do not know which permissions to use with the file to maximize security but also grant enough permissions so a user of the flask app can write to the database and the app can read data from it. I know the path is correct and I have tried it in another python file with the same path and the code worked flawlessly. Thanks for any help in advance!

My code:

```
connection = sqlite3.connect(r'Pathtodatabase.db')
```

The full traceback:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app, referer:
response = self.full_dispatch_request(), referer:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request, referer: 
 rv = self.handle_user_exception(e), referer:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception, referer: 
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb), referer:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise, referer: 
  raise value, referer:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request, referer: 
  rv = self.dispatch_request(), referer: 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request, referer: 
 return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args), referer:
 File ", line 271, in upload, referer: 
   (), referer: 
 File , line 144, in , referer:
   connection = sqlite3.connect(r'Pathtodatabase.db'), referer:
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file, referer:
```

Comment: Are you using an absolute path or relative?  If the Flask user needs to read and write, then security is out the window.  It will have to be 0666.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am using a path such as '/var/files/database.db' and would there be any way to secure it?

Comment: Secure it from whom?  How can you possible secure it if all users need to be able to read and write?

Comment: May be just permission error for /var/files folder . See this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48290873/sqlite-permissions-not-enough-for-execution

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I do not think it is a permissions error as I have run it in a separate python script in the same directory and the code has worked.

Comment: This is a web app.  Do you even know what user It is running as?  Do not discard the possibility of a permissions problem yet.  That's the most likely possibility.

Comment: Giving the folder and the databases 0777 permissions solved the issue, but is there any way to secure the databases to make sure security is protected?