# Updating Sqlite table with php yields error 8

Tags: php, sqlite

I'm running a LightSail amazon server with Lamp PHP 8.1 instance and I needed a lightweight DB for my server, so I've installed SQLite. I've created a DB and trying to insert into a table from php code

```
    $db = new SQLite3('/home/bitnami/bot.db', SQLITE3_OPEN_READWRITE);
    $sql = 'insert into users values("' . $id . '", "' . $platform . '", "' . $name . '", "' . $chatId . '", false)';
    logLine($sql);
    $db->exec($sql);
    
    $err = $db-> LastErrorCode();
    logLine("Error code: " . $err);
```

For some reason completely unclear to me, I'm getting error 8: attempt to write a readonly database.

I've tried the following with no success:

- Give 777 permissions on db file
- Change owner of db file to the user which runs apache (daemon)
- Change owner to root
- Shaman dance

When I run the same code with php cli from console it works! But if it runs under apache it doesn't!

Comment: Does user `apache` have write access to the directory the database is in? [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48313394). For the database file itself, the executable bit (777) isn't needed & 660 should be fine.

Comment: @RickN The missing write permission to folder was missing and it fixed the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set Pragma journal mode in WAL to use read write functions

```
$db = new SQLite3('yourfile.db');
$db->query("PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL");
```